# Time field values not displayed in Lightning component when used recordForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-recordeditform, lightning-record-form, lightning-record-page

I have created one lightning component in which displaying record using **lightning:recordForm**. But, for the fields with type as Time value is not getting displayed, but if I click on edit then value appears in edit box. I have added this component on lightning record page. No issue of access as value can be seen in Related Lists.

Also Time format is not as per user in edit view.

Component:

```
                          recordId="{!v.relatedRecordId}"
                          objectApiName="Working_Hours__c"
                          layoutType="Full"
                          mode="view"
                          columns="2"/>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: While I don't know why you see what you see here, I do know that support for Time fields is somewhat poor even in the LWC lightning-record-form; they are always in ISO format and require at least HH:MM:SS input to work. Not at all effective for most use cases. I pointed this out to the Salesforce PM for the lightning components almost a year ago and he agreed, but I think they have many other things they are focusing on that are higher priority for them.